# I get the following error when adding my Instagram account on Ubuntu Touch tablet

Tags: ubuntu-touch, instagram

I get the following error when adding my Instagram account on my Ubuntu Touch tablet.

```
{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "You are not a sandbox user of this client"}
```

Comment: How are you adding your account?